# Using Processing Framework in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-2, import

I am writing a plugin for QGIS 2.0, and I want to use the processing framework to call some functions.

When I open the Python Console inside QGIS, I am able to call it like this:

```
>>> import processing
```

And then, for instance:

```
>>> processing.alglist()
```

However, if I try to import it in my Python Plugin, it fails to find the processing include:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import processing
```

I googled the problem and found these directives:

```
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
from processing.core.ProcessingConfig import Setting, ProcessingConfig
```

Unfortunately, it also does not work for me.

Does anybody know how to include the QGIS processing framework in a plugin, and how to call the algorithm (let us say for instance `processing.runalg(...)`?

I found many explanations on how to do it in the Python Console, but not outside QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

Using **exactly** the same imports as in the Python console works; is just a problem of pydev, that doesn't recognize the libraries (I probably need to add a reference in the project somewhere)